# iOS edit UIButton properties

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton

I am working on the basics of iOS development.

So far I have a button that on press, will show some text. But what I want to do is after it is pressed, I want it to then change the text of the button, so far this is what I have:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
//button.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
button.titleLabel.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
button.frame = CGRectMake(25, 100, 275, 60);
[button setTitle:@"Press this button to reveal the text!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(button_method:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.view addSubview:button];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)button_method:(UIButton *)sender {
NSString *test = @"I am learning Objective-C for the very first time! Also, this is my first ever variable!";
// handle button press
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 25, 275, 60)];
label.text = test;
label.numberOfLines = 0;
label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
//label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping; //iOS 6 only
[self.view addSubview:label];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

When I try adding `[button setTitle:@"You pressed the button"];` to button_method

This doesn't work... why? And how would I make it work?

Comment: You don't currently have a `button` variable in button_method. Can you show us the code that doesn't work? And you will be more confidently accepted in the objective-C community if you adopt camelCase throughout, not `button_method` but `buttonMethod`.

Comment: Did you try `[sender setTitle:@"new title"];`? The `UIButton` variable is `sender` in the `button_method` method, not `button`.

Comment: ok.. never thought of that!

Comment: @rmaddy it works but what is this about IBOutlet?

Comment: @muqman IBOutlets are only needed if you're creating the button in interface builder. But it looks like you're setting it up pragmatically so it is not necessary...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I try adding `[button setTitle:@"You pressed the button"];` to button_method, it doesn't work... why?

Because that method is nonexistent on `UIButton`.

> And how would I make it work?

By using a method that `UIButton` **actually responds to.** For example:

```
[sender setTitle:@"You pressed the button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

And read the relevant documentation, please.

Comment: @muqman You're welcome, but really, please next time make the effort to read the documentation of a class you're planning to use - it makes life easier for everyone.

Comment: Sorry mate, I know what you mean but this is my first day programming in objective-c once I get a grip on it, i'll be reading the documentation. For some reason, reading the documentations doesn't help me when starting something new.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will not change the title of the button. But simply add a label as a subview for your view. Is this what you want?

If you want to change the text on the button you will want to do `sender.title.text = test;` in your button_method

I also recommend adding a `NSLog(@"Button pressed");` to your button press method to double check that it is being called.